# VueJS - Auto bind parent object in child component with emit, why?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, javascript-objects, emit

It's a bit hard to telling this scenario. But I'll try.

I have an child component. This component will send an object to parent with `$emit`

`this.$emit("get-condition", this.sendData);`

This is sendData structure of sending in `$emit`. This data structure bind with v-model directive in form elements.

```
sendData: {
           selectedValue: null,
           cond: null,
           inTime: null,
           operand: null,
           inTimeValue: null,
           compareValue: null
 }
```

In parent, I have an empty object and assign the data into this object.

```
setCondition(obj) {

   this.$set(this.mockConditions, this.mockKey++ , obj);
},
```

After that I have an object like this in parent. I mean I pass the data from child to parent. It's ok right now.

```
0: Object {
    compareValue:"25"
    cond:"Average"
    inTime:null
    inTimeValue:"23"
    operand:null
    selectedValue:"Flow"
}
```

At this point in child form binding with parent object. If open child form and enter some new values to form elements, it affected in parent object with created `$emit` event.

How to seperate them after `$emit` event ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `obj` parameter passed to `setCondition`method is a reference to `sendData` attribute. To unbind that reference you can clone the object before emitting it:

```
this.$emit("get-condition", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.sendData)));
```

Comment: Yes, it's referenced to sendData. That's the solution for me. Thanks a lot.